# Centering images in iframes

Tags: css, iframe

I have an iframe  `<iframe src="preloader.gif" id="graphFrame"...></iframe>` . I would like to centre the image inside the iframe. I have tried looking up solutions online but none of them work. Can this be done with simple css? If not, is there another solution?

Comment: Why is the image inside an iframe? Curious to know the use-case for this.

Comment: Its going to act like a preloader image so when the actual content loads it will superimpose over the preloader image.

Comment: Is that the best practice for achieving it these days? I'm sure there are better options out there. Just saying.

Comment: Its not really a preloader, its just there so that the user knows that something is happening when they click because the content takes a while to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're serving an image not an html page so CSS doesn't apply.

> Its going to act like a preloader
>   image so when the actual content loads
>   it will superimpose over the preloader
>   image

That being the case I'd suggest that you:

1. Make the iframe's background transparent by setting
   `allowTransparency="true"` That property-name is case-sensitive in Internet Explorer iirc.
2. Apply the following styles to the iframe:

   ```
   background-image: url('preloader.gif');
   background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;
   ```
3. Park the `src` on an html page with a transparent background

   ```
   html, body {
     background-color: transparent;
   }
   ```

Once the content loads in the iframe it'll cover the loading image. [Working Example](http://antisanity.net/projects/examples/iframe.html)

Comment: how can I centre the image then without having to make an html page for it and centering it inside that page?

Comment: by transparent background do you mean setting the iframe's style to `opacity:0` ?

Comment: You can still see the preloader under my graph D=

Answer (score 0):

I needed to center an image in an iframe, and I couldn't get CSS to do anything, so instead of loading the image itself, I put the image in a small html page with an inline style on the body tag of padding:0; margin:0; and loaded that into the iframe instead.  Centered it perfectly with no borders around the edges!

Of course, I made the iframe height and width the same as the image's height and width.